# How can I know reason when Android DB open is failed?

Tags: android, database

In my system, there are some problems about DB.
Especially, SettingsProvider's db ( settings.db ) cause this problem.

However, there are some different cases.

1. DB File is removed.
   ( I think it probably caused by checkdisk with sudden power off. )
2. DB File is broken.
   ( DB file is exist but it is broken. )
3. DB file path is removed.
   ( There isn't dir, it is unable to create db file. )

I need to check the causes when db open is failed, and then show the reason to user.
An exception is occurred when db open is failed.
Also, I can't know the failed reason.

How should I check the reasons and show it to user?

Thank you.

Comment: Catching exception throwed by open can't provide enough information. you can check disk path to judge some.

Comment: Can you take some code. For example: how you getting info from DB?

Comment: Android SettingsProvider use establishDbTracking( ) function.
establishDbTracking arg is Android User number ( usually it is 0. )

And I think Android database classes automatically get this packages UID and file path.
So, I can get any infomation about db before open it.
( After succeed to open db, SettingsProvider get SQLiteDatabase. and it has db's info. )